# What is a word processor and a type setter? (and a "powerpoint" type program)

Tags: vocabulary

What would you call:

- latex (a type setter)
- MS Word (a word processor)
- iWork Pages (a word processor)

What about:

- latex
- MS Word
- iWork Pages
- Powerpoint
- Excel

Is there a term for these programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *LaTeX* : While LaTeX can be loosely called a typesetting program/system, it is officially a [document preparation system](http://www.latex-project.org/) and technically a [document markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) based on TeX, which is the actual [typesetting program/system/language](http://www.tug.org/begin.html) behind LaTeX. However, you will find TeX and LaTeX used interchangeably in most situations.
- *iWork Pages* : This is a word processor or desktop publishing/productivity (DTP) program/software.
- *MS Word* : This is indeed a word processor; could also be DTP
- *Powerpoint/Keynote* : Presentation software/programs; also desktop productivity tools.
- *Excel* : Spreadsheet program/package

Put together, programs in the Office or iWork suite can be generally referred to as office productivity/desktop productivity/desktop publishing programs or tools.